# Use simplexml_load_file php function to load gmail feed

Tags: php, gmail, simplexml

I need to connect my php script to Gmail Atom feed to retrieve the count of unread
messages, but I have problem on get the xml feed file:

```
if($xmlGmailFeed = simplexml_load_file("https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom/")) 
    $unreadMessages = $xmlGmailFeed->fullcount;
```

gives: failed to load external entity
ho can I do? thaks :)

error! failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sounds like a authentication error. I believe you have to authenticate using curl, as `simplexml_load_file` don't suffice. Take a look at the [GmAtom class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3516.html). It will do the trick, or at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/
```

Answer (score 0):

first try and do a file_get_contents to see if the feed is ok and you have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled.
Then you could try and save it a temporary file and pass that path to simplexml_load_file.

If the above work, and you have php < 5.1.0 you could try and do

```
simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode("https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@gmail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom/"))
```

Since PHP 5.1.0 you don't need to do this because PHP will do it for you.

Comment: I use php 5.3.0, I think it's an authorization problem